# How do I use Simplepie to parse an RSS Feed (using a custom namespace) within a Wordpress template?

Tags: wordpress, rss, simplepie

I'm trying to parse a third-party RSS feed on my Wordpress site, using [fetch_feed](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed).

In addition to the standard `<title>`, `<link>`, and `<description>` elements, the feed I'm trying to parse contains several custom elements, using a custom namespace.

e.g. `<foo:venue>`, `<foo:genre>`, `<foo:show>`

I want to display these custom elements on my template, but I can't work out how to do it. Can anyone offer any help or point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The SimplePie website has documentation on how to [Grab Custom Tags or Attributes](http://simplepie.org/wiki/tutorial/grab_custom_tags_or_attributes).

The code for your first example tag would look something like this:

```
$venue = $item->get_item_tags('foo', 'venue');
```